# M-Audio FastTrack Pro levels are very low

Tags: audio-recording

I'm curious if anyone else has experienced very low levels from the mic pres on the FastTrack Pro.
Whenever I use it, I have to crank the gain for the corresponding channel almost to its max before I get a decent input level in my recording software. I've tried several mics and cables.
Has anyone else experienced this with the FastTrack Pro?

Comment: Do you have the Line/Inst button set to "Line"?

Answer (score 1):

I use a Fast Track Ultra that I've always thought had low levels for each of its preamps, but nothing so extreme as needing to crank the gain all the way up just to get a usable level.

The Ultra has an optional -20dB pad on each of its preamps which is enabled by pulling the gain dial out.  Check to see if your Pro has a similar pad which might be enabled erroneously.  The documentation should say if such a thing exists, or it might be written on the device somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I've checked the Pad buttons, doesn't seem to help, both channels are the same

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked whether the 'pad' button on the front of the unit by the input jack is depressed? If it is, the signal is severely quietened, designed to cope with very hot inputs like drum mics without distorting them. I don't mean to be patronising, but I made that mistake once :/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I've checked the Pad buttons, doesn't seem to help, both channels are the same

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem with a Firewire Solo and I'm pretty sure the problem is my mic cable, not the interface.  I know you said you tried it with various cables and mics, but did you prove that you had a working and 100% loud enough cable and mic on another system before you tried it on the M-Audio?

Answer (score 1):

I use the Fast Track Ultra, you need a mic preamp to boost the signal coming in. You can try getting a single channel mic preamp to boost the signal a bit and you will get the best out of you interface.